# for any $k\in N$, p.v$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\cos kx}{t-x}dx=?$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, harmonic-analysis

We know that the Hilbert transform of cosine function is sine,see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HilbertTransform.html.

Now, we don't integral from
$-\infty \to \infty$. We integral from $a \to b(0<a<b)$. My question is:

For any $k\in N$,

$$p.v.\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\cos kx}{t-x}dx=?$$

where [the Cauchy principal value](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyPrincipalValue.html) is taken in  the integrals.

Comment: [This one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/652933/85343) is related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The Maple command $$int(cos(k*x)/(t-x), x = a .. b, CauchyPrincipalValue)\,assuming \,t > a, t <b, k >0  $$ outputs $$-{\it Si} \left( ak-tk \right) \sin \left( tk \right) +\cos \left( tk
 \right) {\it Ci} \left( -ak+tk \right) +{\it Si} \left( bk-tk
 \right) \sin \left( tk \right) -{\it Ci} \left( bk-tk \right) \cos
 \left( tk \right) 
  .$$ See [Si](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Ci) for info.

Comment: @The downvoter: Don't laugh the people.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a < t < b$, just do
$$ \text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{cos(kx)}{(x-t)} \, dx - \int_{-\infty}^a \frac{cos(kx)}{(x-t)} \, dx - \int_{b}^\infty \frac{cos(kx)}{(x-t)} \, dx .$$
And if you don't have $a\le t\le b$, then its not a principle value.  (And if $t=a$ or $t=b$ then the integral is some kind of infinite value unless by chance $\cos(ka)$ or $\cos(kb)$ happen to be zero.)

And of course Si and Ci are just names for integrals we don't know how to evaluate (namely $\sin(x)/x$ and $\cos(x)/x$).  So they are bound to appear in the answer.